# Nest js convert module from forRoot to forRootAsync

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, node-modules, nest-dynamic-modules

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [SupertokensService, AuthService],
  exports: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
  static forRoot({
    connectionURI,
    apiKey,
    appInfo,
  }: AuthModuleConfig): DynamicModule {
    return {
      providers: [
        {
          useValue: {
            appInfo,
            connectionURI,
            apiKey,
          },
          provide: ConfigInjectionToken,
        },
      ],
      exports: [],
      imports: [],
      module: AuthModule,
    };
  }
}
```

The problem with this implementaion I can't use env variables, so I need **useFactory** to pass ConfigService. Can somebody do that, and give some explanation.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am facing the same issue with Supertokens.

Comment: yes, I wrote the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure out how to make this work, unfortunately it only works with nest.js version 9 (current latest version). First you need to create a new file. For example `auth.module-definition.ts`. Now in this file we need to create `ConfigurableModuleBuilder`.

```html
import { ConfigurableModuleBuilder } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthModuleConfig } from './config.interface';

export const { ConfigurableModuleClass, MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN } =
  new ConfigurableModuleBuilder<AuthModuleConfig>()
    .setClassMethodName('forRoot')
    .build();
```

we need to set `setClassMethodName('forRoot')`, when we set `forRoot` it will create two methods, `forRoot` and `forRootAsync`. The next step is to extend our created `ConfigurableModuleClass`. it should look something like this

```html
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AuthMiddleware } from './auth.middleware';
import { SupertokensService } from './supertokens/supertokens.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ConfigurableModuleClass } from './auth.module-definition';;

@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [SupertokensService, AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule extends ConfigurableModuleClass {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

And that's actually it, so from now on we have `forRootAsync` and we get reigister it in `app.module.ts`

```html
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigType } from '@nestjs/config';
import authConfig from './auth/auth.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [authConfig.KEY],
      imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(authConfig)],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigType<typeof authConfig>) => {
        return {
          connectionURI: config.CONNECTION_URI,
          appInfo: {
            appName: config.appInfo.APP_NAME,
            apiDomain: config.appInfo.API_DOMAIN,
            websiteDomain: config.appInfo.WEBSITE_DOMAIN,
            apiBasePath: config.appInfo.API_BASE_PATH,
            websiteBasePath: config.appInfo.WEBSITE_BASE_PATH,
          },
        };
      },
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
}
```

here I am using `Nest.js Config`, but you don't need to, so use it how you want.
I know that my english is not the best, so if you still do not understand you can check these sources https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#configurable-module-builder
https://trilon.io/blog/nestjs-9-is-now-available#Configurable-module-builder

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be compatible with v6 + and 9+ as well you can make a new provider.

```js
import { MySql2Database } from 'drizzle-orm/mysql2';
import { DRIZZLE_ORM } from './constants';
import { NestDrizzleService } from './nest-drizzle.service';
import { PostgresJsDatabase } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import { BetterSQLite3Database } from 'drizzle-orm/better-sqlite3';

export const connectionFactory = {
  provide: DRIZZLE_ORM,
  useFactory: async (nestDrizzleService: {
    getDrizzle: () => Promise<
      MySql2Database | PostgresJsDatabase | BetterSQLite3Database
    >;
  }) => {
    return nestDrizzleService.getDrizzle();
  },
  inject: [NestDrizzleService],
};
```

Provide is made to use a token (best practices):

```js
@Inject(DRIZZLE_ORM) private readonly db: PostgresJsDb
```

And use it like:

```js
public static forRootAsync(options: NestDrizzleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: NestDrizzleModule,
      providers: [...this.createProviders(options)],
      exports: [...this.createProviders(options)],
    };
  }

  private static createProviders(options: NestDrizzleAsyncOptions): Provider[] {
    if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
      return [this.createOptionsProvider(options)];
    }

    return [
      this.createOptionsProvider(options),
      {
        provide: options.useClass,
        useClass: options.useClass,
      },
    ];
  }
```